# ios APNS php server

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cert-dev.pem');
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
echo $txt = "Failed to connect: $error $errorString\n";
}
else {
echo $txt = "Connection to server OK\n";
}
```

I always get `failed to connect: 0`
I tried lot of different methods and nothing seems to work
Anyoone else had this problem? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the DOCUMENT_ROOT variable from the local_cert path:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert-dev.pem');
```